# Get data from popup window to parent window in Magento

Tags: magento

I am working on a Magento module that has a Form where a user has to enter a order number. So for this I have included a button in the form that opens a popup window that displays the list of orders.

Heres what i have done
This is the code for the button that opens the popup

```
<button type="button" class="form-button" onclick="window.open(\''
.Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('*/inventory_receipt/selectOrder',array()
.'\',\'\',\'height=500,width=550\');"><span>'                               
.Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Lookup Order')
.'</span></button>
```

Then i have created a selectOrder Action in the controller that displays a grid that is almost similar to the grid in the sales/order (just modified Grid.php from sales/order).

Now what i want to implement is when the user clicks on an order, the parent form should be populated with the selected order number and close the popup window.
Can any help on how to get this done? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing.
I Followed the steps over [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/32613/), created an extra column with a button that populates the parent window.
Code for the same is below

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{
return '<button type="button" class="form-button" onclick="opener.document.getElementById(\'reference_id\').value='.$row->getIncrementId().'; window.close();"><span>'
            .Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Select Order')
            .'</span></button>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the javascript window.opener reference inside the popup to execute javascript in the original document.

But maybe it would be a better idea not to use an window.open popup but some kind of html layer.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem i had was how to make the row clickable and execute the js after that. In the end i ended creating a new column with a link that calls the js function.